# how to edit /etc/phps/apache2/php.ini

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cloud9-ide

I want to run [open-school](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-open-school/) using cloud9. To make it run, they ask to make some change at php.ini files. But I'm not sure if I can edit this /etc/phps/apache2/php.ini at cloud9.

I already put a php.ini at the root, so the phpinfo() resulted in:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2 
Loaded Configuration File   /home/ubuntu/workspace/php.ini

The open-shool instalation process ask for modifying both php.ini files.

Comment: Are you doing this on your local machine? If so, I am not sure what the problem is. What changes do the docs ask for? What problems are you having?

Comment: @halfer I'm using cloud9, it is an onlline IDE. I can't do it at my local machine. Take a look at http://c9.io.

Comment: OK. Are there support docs at c9 for modifying PHP ini files inside their Docker environment?

Comment: Come to think of it, is it at all different from modifying a php.ini in a normal LAMP environment? An answer below suggests that it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` from the terminal. Run

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

It is not possible yet to edit files outside of the home directory in the Cloud9 editor.

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded the new php.ini files in the folder asked by open-school (copying from php5 project at GITHUB) like this:

```
    $ sudo cp ~/workspace/php.ini /etc/php5/apache2 <br>
```

Must keep one copy of php.ini at ~/workspace

After that I instaled PHP5 curl extension with:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Then Restarted:

```
    $ apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to edit php.ini, then you can use ini_set() function to set any parameter of php.ini.

Just follow the URL http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php to review.